# Attribute Directive written in angular2 cannot be used from angular 1 app with downgrade?

Tags: angularjs, angular2-directives, angular2-components

This is strange, I was downgrading a lot of components from Angular 2 to Angular 1 app and everything working great. I was thinking directive will work too, but seems they don't?

This is my downgrade of directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('tooltip', downgradeComponent({component: TooltipDirective, inputs: ['tooltip', 'placement']}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory);
```

Thats not helping. I know that directive is a component without a template, but it still a component.

Comment: Did you figure out how to make directives work ?